# SQL: JSON Extract from nested object

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table like this

| id | obj |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"is_from_shopping_bag":true,"products":[{"price":{"amount":"18.00","currency":"USD","offset":100,"amount_with_offset":"1800"},"product_id":"1234","quantity":1}],"source":"cart"} |  |  |  |
| 2 | {"is_from_shopping_bag":false,"products":[{"price":{"amount":"80.00","currency":"USD","offset":100,"amount_with_offset":"8000"},"product_id":"2345","quantity":1}],"source":"pdp"} |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

I am doing a sql query in Hive to get the 'currency' field.

Currently I can run

```
SELECT
    JSON_EXTRACT( obj, '$.products')
FROM my_table
```

Which returns

| obj |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [{"price":{"amount":"18.00","currency":"USD","offset":100,"amount_with_offset":"1800"},"product_id":"1234","quantity":1}] |  |  |  |
| [{"price":{"amount":"80.00","currency":"USD","offset":100,"amount_with_offset":"8000"},"product_id":"2345","quantity":1}] |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |

How do I go a layer deeper to get the currency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the currency of the first product use:

```
SELECT
    id,JSON_EXTRACT( obj, '$.products[0].price.currency') first_product_currency
FROM my_table;
```

| id | first_product_currency |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "USD" |
| 2 | "USD" |

---

To get the currency of all the products use:

```
SELECT
    id,JSON_EXTRACT( obj, '$.products[*].price.currency') multiple_currencies
FROM my_table;
```

| id | multiple_currencies |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["USD"] |
| 2 | ["USD"] |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jDnaT9ZBj4C9zNGSHSuk8g/0)